# Scrape yt formatted strings with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I've tried to scrape yt-formatted strings with BeautifulSoup, but it always gives me an error. Here is my code:

```py
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPyMcv4yIDfETZXoJms1XFA')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
def onoroff():
    onoroff = soup.find('yt-formatted-string',{'id','subscriber-count'}).text
    return onoroff


print("Subscribers:  "+str(onoroff().strip()))
```

This is the error I get

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Is there another way to scrape yt-formatted-strings?

Comment: Most of `Youtube` content is generated via JavaScript, capability that `BeautifulSoup` don't have. What info are you trying to get from that page? Subscriber count? You may get luck by scrapping the `json objects` on the source code, but not the `html` element directly.Update: The subscriber count, among other infos, is contained on a `json object`: https://i.imgur.com/ORk6xD8.jpg

Comment: I'll post an answer soon exemplifying my last comment.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Oh ok I just saw your new comment, it didnt load when I was sending the one before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of Youtube content is generated via JavaScript, capability that BeautifulSoup don't have, but you can get luck by **scraping** the json objects on the source code, but not the HTML elements directly, i.e.:

```
import requests, json, re

h = {
    'Host': 'www.youtube.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,pt;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
    'Referer': 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPyMcv4yIDfETZXoJms1XFA',
}
u = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPyMcv4yIDfETZXoJms1XFA"
html = requests.get(u, headers=h).text

# lets get the json object that contains all the info we need from the source code and convert it into a python dict that we can use later
matches = re.findall(r'window\["ytInitialData"\] = (.*\}\]\}\}\});', html, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
if matches:
    j = json.loads(matches[0])
    # browse the json object and search the info you need : https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.123ad9bb8bbe498c95f291c32962aad2
    # We are now ready to get the the number of subscribers (among other info):

    subscribers = j['header']['c4TabbedHeaderRenderer']['subscriberCountText']['runs'][0]["text"]
    print(subscribers)
    # 110 subscribers
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/93bf7b21eb)

Comment: You're welcome. You can scarp almost anything using this technique, just get used to the `json` object keys and values structure and to match the `json` object on the source code of the page. Time, practice and patience will be your friends :)  GL!